# Let $S:V \rightarrow W$ and $T:V \rightarrow W$ be linear transformations.

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, linear-transformations

a) Suppose $S$ and $T$ are injective. Is $S+T$?

b) Suppose $S$ and $T$ are surjective. Is $S+T$?

My answer for a) was:
Let $v_1,v_2 \in V$. Consider:

$(S+T)(v_1) = (S+T)(v_2)$

$(S+T)(v_1) - (S+T)(v_2) = 0$

$S(v_1) + T(v_1) - S(v_2) - T(v_2) = 0$

$S(v_1 - v_2) + T(v_1 - v_2) = 0$

$S(v_1 - v_2) = -T(v_1 - v_2)$

So as long as $S$ produces a value equal to $-T$ then ker($T$) = $W$ and so it is not trivial and not injective. Is this an adequate proof and also, since they always produce 0, does this even qualify as mapping to $W$?

For b) can I get a hint to get me started?

Comment: You only need to find explicit counter examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right idea. Here is a simple counterexample for both statements: let $V = W = \mathbb{R}$, and let $S v = v$ and $T v = -v$. Each is *bijective*, hence injective and surjective. But $S + T$ maps everything to $0 \in W$; it is neither injective nor surjective.